# Verilog syntax error near "<=" within a case statement

Tags: verilog

In this snippet of code:

```
    reg [4:0] status_led = 5'b00100;
    case (status_led)
        default: begin                   
            if (rotation) begin
                status_led[4] <= status_led[3];
                status_led[3] <= status_led[2];
                status_led[2] <= status_led[1];
                status_led[1] <= status_led[0];
                status_led[0] <= status_led[4];
            end else if (~rotation) begin
                status_led[4] <= status_led[0];
                status_led[3] <= status_led[4];
                status_led[2] <= status_led[3];
                status_led[1] <= status_led[2];
                status_led[0] <= status_led[1];
            end
        end
    endcase
```

I get the error "syntax error near <=". Why is this an error?

Comment: What comes before the code you've shown? Is this part of an `always` block or a function?

Comment: And why do you bother to use a `case` statement with nothing but a `default` case?

Comment: This code is on its own. Originally I had other cases but I changed the code. I have already replaced this code with superior code, but I am curious as to why I get the aforementioned error in case I need to write similar code in the future

Comment: you cannot have a stand-alone `case` in verilog. it must be contained within a procedural block, such as 'always'.

Comment: @Serge a `case` outside of an `always`/`initial` a legal generate construct (being inside `generate`-`endgenerate` is optional). For this particular problem, the `case` needs to be inside a sequential `always` block (ex `always @(posedge clk)`)

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined your case inside always, hence the error. This should solve your problem. A good idea would be not to mix combinational and sequential always blocks together.

```
  reg [4:0] status_led = 5'b00100;

  always@(posedge clk) begin
    case (status_led)
        default: begin                   
            if (rotation) begin
                status_led[4] <= status_led[3];
                status_led[3] <= status_led[2];
                status_led[2] <= status_led[1];
                status_led[1] <= status_led[0];
                status_led[0] <= status_led[4];
            end else if (~rotation) begin
                status_led[4] <= status_led[0];
                status_led[3] <= status_led[4];
                status_led[2] <= status_led[3];
                status_led[1] <= status_led[2];
                status_led[0] <= status_led[1];
            end
        end
    endcase
   end
```